# Maven dependencies from custom repository are not being included

Tags: maven

I am migrating my project from ant build to maven. For the third party dependencies, we have been using a custom maven repository (url http://SOME_IP/libs).I have defined this repository in my pom file and included these dependency like this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thus all dependencies are getting downloaded in .m2/repository/lib but when I run mvn compile it gives me compilation error saying that those package doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `scope` to `runtime`, the dependencies are not available for compilation. You need to set `scope` to `compile` (or leave it out, which is the same).

Comment: Thanks @JF Meier.. Saved the day